# Semicolon before throw statement

Tags: sql-server

Why is a semicolon required before a `throw` statement?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/throw-transact-sql

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons

Comment: Actually, you should specify semi-colons after each statement and problem solved. Not using statement terminators is deprecated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can resolve some ambiguities

Compare

```
BEGIN TRAN THROW --Starts a transaction named "THROW"
BEGIN TRY
    SELECT 1 / 0
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRAN
    THROW /*Rolls back the transaction named "THROW"*/
END CATCH
```

To

```
BEGIN TRAN THROW --Starts a transaction named "THROW"
BEGIN TRY
    SELECT 1 / 0
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRAN; /*rolls back the tran without caring about the name*/
    THROW --rethrows the error
END CATCH
```

Comment: And another bad one [` SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE()
 THROW`](http://www.dbdelta.com/always-use-semicolon-statement-terminators/)

Comment: @DanGuzman - thanks - that is less convoluted than my example.

Comment: I don't think your example is at all convoluted and maybe even a common accident waiting to happen in the wild.